# how to handle these function in a more idiomatic rxjs way

Tags: rxjs

I am new to rxjs (the project is stuck on rxjs 5 for the time being) and I don't really need to refactor sthese functions but as I'm trying to get up to speed with rxjs, how would I not use `toPromise` for an http call:

```
try {
  const response = await this.http.post(`${TokenUrl}`, payload, options).toPromise();
} catch(err) {
  // whatever
}
```

I also have this `setInterval` that periodically pings a server:

```
this.timerId = setInterval(() => {
  this.blobStorageService.ping();
}, 60000);
```

I tried using `interal` but could not quite get the syntax right.

Comment: So what are you trying to do?

Comment: Is `blobStorageService.ping()` returns observable or promise?

Comment: can you add the signature of `blobStorageService.ping()`?